# Android InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD to visible number password (Only Numbers)

Tags: android, android-edittext

I Implemented an Edittext that accepts **numberPassword** and also allows a user to show password & hide password. It works but there is one Issue i cannot solve.

I used `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER and InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD` to hide the password which works, I used `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD` to make it visible.

But then the `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD` also allows user to enter both Characters & numbers but I do NOT want that. **I want users to be able to enter numbers ONLY.**

Please how can I achieve this?

this is my code below:

```
private fun setShowHiddenField(field: TextInputEditText, checked: Boolean){
        if(checked){
            field.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD
        } else {
            field.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD
        }
        field.setSelection(field.getText().toString().length)
    }
```

**Edit**

**For anyone asking why I didn't do it in XML?** Even if you do it in xml, using `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD` would still bring up a keyboard allowing both Texts & Numbers.

I have my code for Edittext below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/cardNumberEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:digits="1234567890"
                tools:ignore="LabelFor,NegativeMargin"/>
```

Think of this like a Edittext accepting a **PIN CODE** that you also want to give users the option to view the PIN & hide it.

I am using a Checkbox to allow user choose to hide or show. So i cannot use password options like `passwordToggleContentDescription` or `passwordToggleEnabled` or `passwordToggleTint`

Comment: you can implement via xml that is too easy.

Comment: @BlackBlind If you do it in Code, you would get the same result after using InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to solve my problem, not a direct solution but it works.

> You might technically see the keyboard change quickly from letters to numbers when using an Emulator, but this works pretty fine on Device as you can hardly notice the quick change except you pay so much attention.

```
private fun setShowHiddenField(field: TextInputEditText, checked: Boolean){
        if(checked){
            field.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD

            // set keyboard back to allowing only digits & specify them
            field.keyListener = DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789")

        } else {
            field.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD
        }
        field.setSelection(field.getText().toString().length)
    }
```